# Capture exception when using async method with .Result

Tags: c#, async-await

In general when I use `await` in my async calls, exceptions are captured correctly:

```
try {
   return await DoSomethingAsync();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   // Exception is captured here
}
```

The only requirement for the code above to work is the **method must be async**.

However, I have a method that cannot be async as it is a delegate, therefore I cannot use `await`. Using `.Result` makes my catch block to never capture anything.

```
try {
   return DoSomethingAsync().Result;
} catch (Exception ex) {
   // This block never gets called
}
```

Is there any way to capture exceptions when using `.Result`? Or I should try a different approach?

**Edit 1: Body of method DoSomethingAsync**

```
public async Task<string> DoSomethingAync() {
   return await CallAThirdPartyLibrary();
}
```

**Edit 2: Caller of method DoSomethingAsync**

```
Bind<Foo>()
   .ToFactory(c => new FooBar(CallMyMethodThatIsNotAsyncAndIsUsingDotResult()))
   .PerRequest();
```

How could I make the caller use `await` so I could get rid of the `.Result`?

Comment: Check here. it explains why i don't catch the exception https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: `.Result` had to throw `AggregateException` at least. What is the body of `DoSomethingAsync`?

Comment: @Yarik I've updated the question

Comment: Does `.Result` ever returns or there is a deadlock?

Comment: @Yarik it never returns, so guessing it's causing a deadlock

Comment: @AndreFeijo, Which is what happens when you mix blocking calls `.Result` and async calls. Take some time and read the article if you want to learn how to work around it

Comment: Just add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to `CallAThirdPartyLibrary()` and let's hope your 3rd party library doesn't try to access the UI thread. Then everything should be OK.

Comment: Still deadlocking even with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. Please see my updates

Comment: You have to make sure that `CallAThirdPartyLibrary()` also uses `.ConfigureAwait(false)` for all of its awaits. If you don't have access to that code, I could suggest to call your Ninject initialization logic (is this Ninject?) on background thread using `Task.Run`.